# C# searching for extended ascii characters in string

Tags: c#, search, hex, ascii

I have a file that I am searching for specific ascii characters.

I ran the following code after getting the text from a file:

`var t = text.IndexOf((char)128);`

Hexedit shows I have characters of HEX 80 which is ascii character 128, but t ends up with a value of -1.

Is there another way I should be searching for this character?

Comment: You have to take into account the encoding used to save the original file, and the encoding you are using to load that file's content in your string (your `text` variable).

You have different formats of encoding (ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16), so, a character on your file could be composed of one or two bytes (depending on encoding).

When the framework converts `(char)128`, it used a default encoding... witch could be different from the one used to load the file.

Comment: Maybe you can post more of your code (maybe the file content/encoding and the code you are using to load the file), to have better context.

Comment: Thanks CicheR.  Setting the appropriate encoding when reading the file was the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I had to make a change to my encoding appropriately like the following in order be able to search the string as I expect to.  In my case it was the following:

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(filename, Encoding.UTF7);
```